# expo-router replace to new page then crashes

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I send a http request then I accept result data, and router a new page.
but APP crashes! I don't know why……

I use iOS simulator ,iOS version is 17.4

code:
`verificationCode(params.phoneNum as string,text).then( (resultJson) => {                 router.replace('/main/Main');})`

I try to router.push('/main/Main'),this normal working, only replace() will crashes
but I really need replace to new page